# PDO Update Function sets same value to every column - loop error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

For some reason I can't work out when I pass the following values to my database record update function, it sets the same value to every column.

Here's the data I'm passing it:

```
  $_values = array(
    'client_fname' => $_POST['client_fname'],
    'client_lname' => $_POST['client_lname'],
    'client_email' => $_POST['client_email']
);
$_args= array('client_id' => $_id);  
$db->dbUpdate('client', $_values, $_args)
```

It updates every column (client_fname, client_lname, client_email) to the $_id value, instead of the posted values. And I can't work out what I've done wrong :(

Here's the query it creates before binding params:

```
 UPDATE client SET client_fname=:0, client_lname=:1, client_email=:2 WHERE client_id=:w0
```

Here's the function

```
 public function dbUpdate($_table, $_values, $_args) { //TODO: Fix Function
    try {
        $query = 'UPDATE '.$_table.' SET ';
        $i = 0; foreach ($_values as $_field => $_value) {
            if($i == 0) {
                $query .= $_field.'=:'.$i;
            } else {
                $query .= ', '.$_field.'=:'.$i;
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $query .= ' WHERE ';
        $i = 0; foreach ($_args as $_field => $_value) {
            if($i == 0) {
                $query .= $_field.'=:w'.$i;
            } else {
                $query .= ', '.$_field.'=:w'.$i;
            }
            $i++;
        }

        $sql = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $i = 0; foreach ($_values as $_field => $_value) {
            $sql->bindParam(':'.$i, $_value); $i++;
        } 
        $i = 0; foreach ($_args as $_field => $_value) {
            $sql->bindParam(':w'.$i, $_value); $i++;
        } 

        if($sql->execute()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        print_r($e->errorInfo);
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: extract the executed query please.

Comment: although your current code is not vulnerable to injection, dbUpdate function alone is.

Comment: `UPDATE client SET client_fname=:0, client_lname=:1, client_email=:2 WHERE client_id=:w0`

It looks like the issue is with the bind param loop?

Comment: It is exacly a problem with bindParam loop:  Take a look at the detailed explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667807/pdo-multiple-named-placeholders-doesnt-retrieve-data/13668536#13668536

Comment: Thank you so much, switching from bindParam to bindValue fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've answered this a few times before, so I will link to my previous answer.

In short, bindParam requires a reference. It binds the variable, not the value, to the statement. Since the variable in a foreach loop is reset at the start of each iteration, only the last reference is left intact, and you end up binding all your placeholders to it.

Detailed explanation here: [PDO bindParam issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667807/pdo-multiple-named-placeholders-doesnt-retrieve-data/13668536#13668536).

Answer (score -1):

Unlike useless PDO, [real database abstraction libraries](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) will let you avoid such a mess, making all code into 3 lines

```
$allowed = array('client_fname', 'client_lname', 'client_email');
$insert  = $db->filterArray($_POST,$allowed);
$db->query("UPDATE client SET ?u WHERE client_id=?i",$insert, $_id);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the project needs to be done in PDO as that's the spec requirement.

Comment: this is no answer to the question..and it must be `$db->filterArray($_POST, $allowed)`.