# Dynamic bindparam: only the last is binded

Tags: php

I want generate dynamically insert. I use an array to get value and parameter name. However when I try to run sql all columns get the last parameter I pass it. I have a loop to create bindParam and if I try an output seems that all is ok.

I'm trying this approach:

```
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    foreach($sqlData['columns'] as $param => $value){
        $stmt->bindParam(':' . $param , $value);
        echo $param . "," . $value . "<br>";
    }

    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13668536/1233508

Comment: `$stmt->bindValue(':' . $param , $value);`